# How to confirm if a user is already authenticated in Active DIrectory?

Tags: c#, authentication, active-directory

I know this can be done via WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().IsAuthenticated, but I need another method.

Is there a way we can query Active Directory and find out if a particular user has already been authenticated.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you are talking about, the above manner is using the current user context, which is the only user than can currently be authenticated.

You can query AD with a username/password to try and validate the user, but in terms of current user authentication, that would be the way you mentioned.

Comment: But how does one determine if `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().IsAuthenticated` is a local user account OR an Active Directory account?